# Error obtaining UI hierarchy in UIAutomator

Tags: appium, android-uiautomator

I'm unable to take a screen-shot from the UIAutomator tool. When i am running UIAutomator from the command line (on Ubuntu), I'm getting the following error in the tool:

```
Error obtaining UI hierarchy 
Reason Error while parsing UI hierarchy
XML file: Invalid ui automator hierarchy file
```

And, on the command line, a "**null rootnode after parsing**." message.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: stop the appium server and try again.

Comment: Did that one , but no use same error.